# maple code output does not display on the screen

Tags: output, display, maple

I've just downloaded the  Maple 2020 trial version and I have zero experience on Maple programming. My problem is: when I do simple calculations such as 3+5 or 2*3, the result displays on the screen but, for other functions such as

```
   factor(x^2+2x+1);
```

or assigning variables can't be done:

```
    n:= 5;
    m:=7;
    m+n;
```

I do not see any results on the  display screen after the enter.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: This sounds like a configuration or similar usage question about the Maple GUI (Graphical User Interface), as oppsed to a programming question per se. It's not even clear what mode you are working in (2D Input, plaintext, Document vs Worksheet, etc). Your input might not even be plaintext, so posting plaintext here may be a misrepresentation of what you are trying. I suggest posting at the Maple user forum www.mapleprimes.com and uploading a .mw file attachment of your attempts to your Question there.

Comment: I am using 2d document mode. I don't know what do you mean mu plaintext code?

Comment: If you are using 2D Input in Document mode then the plaintext ASCII code that you have in your question here is not revelant, because in Maple you are inputting in a marked up 2D manner. The plaintext ASCII code above simply cannot show what you problem is. So I will repeat my suggestion that you repost on a forum that allows you to attach your Document, so that it might be inspected for the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like, I need to change some configurations of the Maple. After doing some search online, I found these suggestions in a [web site.](https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/220236-Maple-Doesn-T-Work-In-Pc-With-Windows-10?fbclid=IwAR2EnGZE63jn-tBZ4Q3xJUr26tdzrsZWfZ8rBmp-Px7Uwq-jj_OPT8RGZQI) I have applied the following steps and my problem is solved: (Remember to apply globally not for the session.)

1. Open a new blank worksheet
2. On the toolbar, access Tools->Options.
3. Select the 'Display' tab
4. Ensure that the first entry is set to 'Maple Notation', and the second entry is set to '2-D Math Notation'
5. Click 'Apply to session' at the bottom left
6. On the toolbar, access Tools->Options again
7. Select the 'Interface' tab
8. Ensure that the entry 'Default format for new worksheet' is set to 'Worksheet'
9. Click 'Apply to session' at the bottom left
10. Now open a new worksheet in the same session. There should be a prompt '>'.
11. At the prompt, type 'version();' without the single quotes, but with the trailing semi-colon. This ought to return details of the precise Maple version you are running. If it returns something like

    ```
    User Interface: 1133417

    Kernel: 1133417

    Library: 1133417
    ```

(precise numbers may be different), then you ought to be good to go - so try something simple like 1+1; at the next command prompt, (remember the semicolon).